# Javascript/Ajax How to find date before number of weeks entered by user

Tags: javascript

i am fetching one date "Due date " from system
for certain application I have one requirement like user will enter number of weeks dynamically and from those number of weeks I have to find the date using following formula :-

Due Deadline = Due date-weeks

please help if you have any soln!!!
--Snehal

Answer (score 0):

There is a Date object built into JS. Also, most JS libraries have Date objects with even more functionality.

Using the date object, you can convert it to a timestamp and subtract the number of seconds in a week multiplied by the number of weeks the user entered, rounding down or up depending on your needs.

Read more about the JS Date object at: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var  time = new Date().getTime();
var week =604800000;// 7*24*3600*1000;
var threeWeeksBefore = new Date(time - 3 * week);
var sixWeeksFromNow  = new Date(time + 6 * week);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aqwEv/

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid daylight savings oddities by adding days instead of seconds

```
Date.prototype.addWeeks= function(n, hours, mins){
    var due= new Date(this);
    if(typeof hours== 'number'){
        if(typeof mins!== 'number') mins= 0;
        due.setHours(hours, mins, 0, 0);
    }
    due.setDate(due.getDate()+(n*7));
    return due;
}
```

**new Date().addWeeks(2)** // same time as Date
Tue Sep 20 2011 09:53:56

**new Date().addWeeks(2, 0)** // midnight
Tue Sep 20 2011 00:00:00

**new Date().addWeeks(2, 7,30)** //set hours && minutes
Tue Sep 20 2011 07:30:00